# Strange Behavour with MVC Razor Syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a contact us form which is reused for varying purposes in the site

The rule is that if certain fields are already pre-populated ie the email address or subject is known then these should not be displayed ie becomes a HiddenFor

For the email this works fine, but subject it doesn't and im completely confused as they are identical string fields both required with a MaxLength of 100

```
@model List<TJI.ObjectModel.Entities.Form>
...
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Email))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, new {@class = "control-label  col-sm-3 col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "*")
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    else
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Subject))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Subject, new {@class = "control-label  col-sm-3 col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subject, new {@class = "form-control"})
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Subject, "*")
            </div>
        </div>
    }        
    else
    {
        <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Subject)
        </div>
    }
...

public class Form : EntityBase
{
...
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that i realized i didn't pass the subject accross to the ViewModel in the controller

```
public ActionResult Contact(string contactTypeEnum, string subject, string body, string department )
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(department))
        {
            department = Department.None.ToString();
        }

        var user = GetCurrentUser();

        var model = new FormViewModel
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Department = (Department) Enum.Parse(typeof (Department), department)
        };

        if (user != null)
        {
            model.Name = user.Name;
            model.Email = user.Email;
        }

        CacheEntity(model);

        return IsAjax() ? (ActionResult) PartialView("ContactDetail", model) : View(model);
    }
```